# Detect Circular Dependencies in ES6

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to detect (static analysis tools like eslint, ??) Circular Dependencies in javascript. More like

```
module A imports module B
module B imports module A
```

I had some trouble with this when using @flowtype and like to see where it happening in my moderate size codebase.

My code use ES6 module system and uses babel + webpack to bundle it.

Comment: You probably don't want it as a linter though, you'd have to basically parse every file in the dependency chain. It'd be slowish if you do the checks on every file save.

Comment: thanks @MinusFour. Indeed, my usecase is one time only.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the circular dependency plugin for webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin

You can also use madge to statically detect circular references: https://github.com/pahen/madge

Comment: This is not helpful for non-webpack projects or just to prevent team members from commiting/pushing code which introduces circular dependency. A solution should be regardless or Webpack

Answer (score 70):

You can try [dpdm](https://github.com/acrazing/dpdm), which is definitely better than madge, especially in a mix of javascript and typescript.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of dpdm

Comment: Being able to strip out the TS imports was extremely helpful for finding the "real" circular import issues, thanks!

Comment: dpdm was the solution for me after hours of searching. Great tool, thanks!

Comment: Command 'dpdm' not found when i ddi 'dpdm --help'

Comment: Great tool indeed.

Comment: dpdm is very useful for me. Is there any solution to run it on each webpack watch changes?

Comment: big upvote because dpdm is the only tool I've seen that handles correctly TS path mapping. Maybe I'll be able to track down this circular import problem now!

Comment: This helped me to pinpoint the dependency issue I was debugging for hours in 10 minutes, so definitely a useful tool to have around.

Comment: Hmm i had troubles running the commands after installing the package, idk if this has something to do with me using .tsx/having the public folder somewhere else than root..

Comment: @Shamseer Ahammed, it probably should be installed globally, dpdm have 2 types of installation, choose second one

Comment: absolutely `dpdm` is better than `madge`