# Re-exporting causes asynchronous loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I don’t know if the problem is Vue, Webpack, Javascript, Node, or something else, but I have three files:

`components/MyComponent.vue` a template-only component

`components/index.js`:

```
import ComponentA from './componentA';
import ComponentB from './componentB';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import ComponentD from './componentD';
 
export { ComponentA, ComponentB, MyComponent, ComponentD };
```

`page/SomePage.vue`:

```
<template>
{{ someValue() }}
  <my-component>
  </my-component>
</template>
<script>
import { ComponentA, ComponentB, MyComponent, ComponentD } from '@/assets';
export default {
  name: "SomePage",
  components: {
    MyComponent
  },
  computed: {
    someValue() {
       console.log({ ComponentA, ComponentB, MyComponent, ComponentD });
       return 1;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

## You’d expect

- the template to be rendered in the browser
- `{ ComponentA: (...), ComponentB: (...), MyComponent: (...), ComponentD: (...) }` to be logged several times to the console.

## What happens

- nothing is rendered in the browser
- the line `{ ComponentA: (...), ComponentB: (...), MyComponent: undefined, ComponentD: undefined }` is to the console.
- then the error `Unknown custom element: <my-component> - did you register the component correctly?` is logged
- `{ ComponentA: (...), ComponentB: (...), MyComponent: (...), ComponentD: (...) }` is logged several times to the console.

That is, the import happens — but too late for the registration to succeed. Bypassing the re-export

```
import { ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentD } from '@/assets';
import MyComponent from '@/assetsMyComponent;
```

fixes the problem.

In the words of the English writer, critic, and politician Edward George Bulwer-Lytton, “WTF?”

Comment: does the issue happen when you log them outside computed property for example in mounted hook?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim — the component happens to have no mounted hook; I put it in a computed property just a random to try to see what was going on.  Why, what would it mean if that worked?

Comment: "MyComponent: undefined, ComponentD: undefined" - this looks totally like circular dependency, it's unknown why it's there because the question lacks the full example to reproduce the problem but that's it, it should be avoided. A workaround is to async component and dynamic `import()` to lazily resolve components. "Unknown custom element: <my-component>" - my-component isn't registered in the code above.

Comment: @EstusFlask — it might very well be a circular dependency, but the system is 65+ KSLOC.  Is there a way to have Vue detect a circular dependency and tell me so I can manually unplug it?

Comment: This isn't Vue's responsibility, it's ui framework. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462055/detect-circular-dependencies-in-es6 . That you're able to fix this by changing MyComponent import means it's a part of the problem

Comment: @tony19 — yes, sorry, `PropertyList` was the real name of the component.  Fixed now.