# Infinite HMR updates in React app created with Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, webpack-hmr

I've stumbled upon an issue, of HMR infinitely updating a file when using hot reload mode in vite app. The file seems to be different every time. I've attached a screenshot of the issue below.

[Vite-HMR-infinite-updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Nud.png)

Env:

- OS - Windows 10 and Macos Monterey 12.5
- Node version - v16.14.0
- npm verion - 8.3.1
- vite version - ^3.2.3

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

const getPath = (s: string) => path.resolve(__dirname, s);

const aliases = {
    '@actions': getPath('./src/actions'),
    '@api': getPath('./src/api'),
    '@assets': getPath('./src/assets'),
    '@components': getPath('./src/components'),
    '@config': getPath('./src/config'),
    '@libs': getPath('./src/libs'),
    '@pages': getPath('./src/pages'),
    '@providers': getPath('./src/providers'),
    '@shared': getPath('./src/shared'),
    '@slices': getPath('./src/slices'),
    '@store': getPath('./src/store'),
    '@themes': getPath('./src/themes'),
    '@formComponents': getPath('./src/formComponents'),
    '@hooks': getPath('./src/hooks'),
    '@schemas': getPath('./src/schemas'),
    '@translations': getPath('./src/translations'),
};
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths({ root: '.' })],
    resolve: {
        alias: aliases,
    },
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/yup"],
        "paths": {
            "@actions/*": ["actions/*"],
            "@api/*": ["api/*"],
            "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
            "@components/*": ["components/*"],
            "@config/*": ["config/*"],
            "@libs/*": ["libs/*"],
            "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
            "@providers/*": ["providers/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["shared/*"],
            "@slices/*": ["slices/*"],
            "@store/*": ["store/*"],
            "@themes/*": ["themes/*"],
            "@formComponents/*": ["formComponents/*"],
            "@hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
            "@schemas/*": ["schemas/*"],
            "@translations/*": ["translations/*"],
            "@components/*": ["components/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["./src"]
}
```

- reinstalling node_modules/

Comment: possibly a case of circular dependencies. check whether there are any circular dependencies. [how to check circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57106526/9740955)

Answer (score 0):

Roll back to **3.1** version of vite (Version 4 also has this problem)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).